# datePicker Swift font size row size column size

Tags: swift, fonts, datepicker, uidatepicker

I am working with a date picker in xcode and the code is functioning perfectly. All that I'm having trouble with is that i can't figure how to change the font or font size and i can't figure out how to change the row and column size of the datePicker. Any sample code for formatting the display of the DatePicker would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple guide:

> **Appearance of Date Pickers**
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of date pickers.

[UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html)

However, out there you can find custom implementation that will let you do appearance customization. One of libraries can be found on [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController).